# Why does Drupal url alias field allow apostrophes and passes validation?

Tags: path-aliases

In the node creation form, when a user unchecks the "Automatic alias" checkbox, the user can put apostrophe and other punctuation marks, which is not good in a URL.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: You could always deny them the ability to edit that in the first place via permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) to add your own validation function to node edit forms. In this validation function you'd check for characters that you want to allow/deny, and throw a [form_set_error()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/form_set_error/7) on that field if there's a problem.

Answer (score 1):

As mention you can set them as unavailable characters for the URL. I always install the transliteration module as well. It will help keep your URLs in check